# How do I turn off authentication for retrieving XML schemas from the WSO2 GREG?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Is it possible to turn off authentication so that users don't need to provide username/password retrieving XML schemas using the schema URL of the WSO2 GREG? It doesn't help configuring the role `everyone` to be able to list schemas.

I want to do this until I have configured LDAP integration. Now I have to create a temporary user which I distribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  "wso2.anonymous.role. Add that role to schema resource in resource browser.

"The "wso2.anonymous.role" is a special role that represents a user that has not logged into the WSO2 Governance Registry Management Console. Granting "Read" access to resources for this role would mean that you do not require authentication to access resources using the respective Permalinks. The "everyone" role is a special role that represents a user that has logged into the WSO2 Governance Registry Management Console

Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance460/Managing+Role+Permissions

Comment: I missed that note in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: But how do I access the permissons panel shown in http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance460/Managing+Role+Permissions ? I click "Configure" -> "Users and Roles" -> "Roles". There I dont see wso2.anonymous.role and if I try to add it, it says it is already there...

Comment: You do not have to add it. It is already there. Select schema from resource browser. Schemas-->your schema. And then bottom of the page you can see the permission panel where you can configure permission for different roles. etc.

Comment: Thanks, I found it and tried it. So it is not possible via the management console to allow read access to _all_ Schema permalinks for the anonymous role automatically? Do you have to program that as a Handler? Is there no simpler way?

Comment: I got the answer to my question posted in the comment from "Mar 29 at 11:06" here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757177/how-do-i-give-read-access-to-all-schema-permalinks-to-wso2-anonymous-role