# How do I give read access to all Schema permalinks to "wso2.anonymous.role"?

Tags: wso2, acl

Is it possible via the WSO2 Governance Registry Management Console to allow read access to *all* Schema permalinks for the role "wso2.anonymous.role" automatically? Do you have to program that as a Handler? Is there no simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First SignIn in to G-Reg management console
2. Navigate to  Main --> Resources --> Browse and Find your
   Schema's stored location(Ex: /_system/governance/trunk/schemas)
3. In the middle pane, click on "Detail view" and expand the "Permissions" area.
4. Then select "wso2.anonymous.role" from Role drop down and assign read only permission to that role. Now anyone can access resources store under that Collection

Wiki Doc for [Managing Role Permissions](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Managing+Role+Permissions)

Comment: Thanks! Simple, but powerful!